# Can I mount a Google Cloud NFS volume on my local computer?

Tags: nfs, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I created a NFS node on Google Cloud, and I would like to create a volume mount on my local Mac OSX computer; it seems that I need to connect to the same VPN as the NFS node, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Alternately, if you don't mind opening traffic to the public internet, you could give the NFS machine a public IP address and then connect from the client using that address. Not secure, but will probably be easier than configuring a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [CLOUD FILESTORE](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/) to achieve this.
You need to be in the same VPC (or use a VPN). So from on-prem, you would need a VPN connection to use filestore.

Comment: Thanks! How would I set up this VPN connection? Or how would I be able to get into the same VPC?

Comment: If you wish to setup a VPN tunnel you can use CloudVPN in your project which will setup the site to site VPN with the gateway on your local network side. I suggest reviewing Google Cloud VPN Documentation [1,2,3].                                                 
[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/
[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview
[3] https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/choosing-a-vpn